# How to get nether mobs to spawn at night in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In some servers, nether mobs come out in the regular world, like blazes, ghasts, and Giants every night along with all the other mobs the regularly spawn at night. How can you do this in a single player world? Is there a command for it?

Comment: Yes. you could use some commands/command blocks to make a system that would do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command, and the server probably has a plugin doing it. You *can* use `/summon <Blaze/Ghast/Giant> <X> <Y> <Z>` to try to replicate the in vanilla minecraft.

Answer (score -1):

if you have forge, download TMI or NEI and just get a spawner
you can change the mob by right clicking it with the desired 
spawn egg.

TMI:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272385-toomanyitems-the-inventory-editor-and-more-1-8

NEI:
http://minecraftsix.com/not-enough-items-mod/

Comment: How will these solve the problem?  Just telling someone to download a different mod without explaining how to use them isn't very useful.

Comment: i think it is pretty self-explanatory, very easy if he knows how to use forge.

Comment: What about for the readers that don't?  An answer isn't very useful if all you do is recommend something, without explaining how to use that thing to fulfill the goal.

Comment: okay okay, ill edit it. im just helping i think he just needs a spawner thats it

Answer (score -2):

well actually, you could get some command blocks and set it to spawn mobs every whatever ticks or something, and invert a daylight sensor signal so that the command block is activated at night. be sure to use a repeating command block, but add a delay to it.